# Conditional rewrite Rules in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I have a DNS where I have 3 entries as below

```
    www A 1.1.1.1
    blog A 1.1.1.1
    post A 1.1.1.1
```

Now My main website is www.something.com which is working fine

now i want blog.something.com should redirect to www.something.com/?page_id=2461

&

post.soemthing.com should redirect to  www.something.com/?page_id=2409

DNS and Webserver is on same physical machine.

I am little new to .htaccess codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.something\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.something.com/?page_id=2461 [R=302,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^post\.something\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.something.com/?page_id=2409 [R=302,L,QSA]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.