# How to redirect from one domain to another?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have one domain 
abc.ca is already running & google crawled that url.

Now i'm going for
abc.com

so how can i manage all URL's of abc.ca -> abc.com

using htacees. Site is built in PHP Joomla.

abc.ca/def.html -> abc.com/def.html

there are thousands of pages. I can't write individual 301 redirection in htaccess.

We can do this in PHP

```
$uri =  "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$newUrl = str_replace(".ca", ".com", $uri);
header("Location: " . $newUrl);
```

It's better to do on PHP site or htaccess site?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.abc.\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had simmilar issue but was cross domain one

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163735/conditional-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess/17163863?noredirect=1#comment24849193_17163863)

I got solved my issue via this.

You can even do via cname entries in dns as its in your similar two domains.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but it should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.ca$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /old/old.htm http://www.domain.com/new.htm
```

else you might want to take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
    RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
    RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here you can modify **`RewriteBase /`** into your domain name. 
For sub domain you can give like this **`RewriteBase /subfolder`**